# What port uses Visual Studio to connect to TFS server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, windows-firewall

I'm using TFS Server 2013 en Visual Studio 2013. I want to make the TFS Server available via the internet so that (only) certain developers/ipaddresses can work at home.

My question is: What port does TFS Server use to connect to Visual studio? In other words: What port must I open/forward in my firewall for this to work?

Comment: [Ports required for installation of Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578664.aspx)

Comment: default port is 8080

Answer (score 2):

There is no communication from TFS to Visual Studio as all traffic flows the other way.

Visual Studio connects with 8080 by default and 443 if secured.

I would however recommend that you leave everything to Visual studio online (http://tfs.visualstudio.com) as It is already secured and does not need any firewalls to be opened.